# MySQL - Using COUNT(*) outside the SELECT

Tags: mysql, count

I have this data and I want to return the names of customers in descending order of their count

```
Customer | Count
abc      | 2
efg      | 3
hij      | 7
klm      | 3
```

So for the table above the result should be

```
Customer
hij
efg
klm
abc
```

I have this query

```
Select Customer, Count(*) AS CustomerCount
From 'customers'
group by Customer
order by CustomerCount DESC
```

which gives me

```
Customer | Count
hij      | 7
efg      | 3
klm      | 3
abc      | 2
```

But I don't want to display the count and I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help me?

Comment: show us the html markup where you are using echo query result. Changing the query would't solve your problem. You need to remove the echo of the count in your Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL lets you order by an aggregate function without including it in the select clause, so this should work for you:

```
Select Customer
From customers
group by Customer
order by COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` without having `COUNT(*)` in the select expression.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for you problem:

```
Select Customer, Count(*)
From 'customers'
order by count(*) DESC
group by Customer
```